# jQuery: focus on window (Google Chrome?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var y = 0;
var focus = true;

$(window).bind('focus', function() {
    if(!focus) {        
        console.log("Hello");
        document.title = "title";
        focus = true;
    }
});

$(window).bind('blur', function() {
    if(focus) {
        document.title = "title (" + y + ")";
        focus = false;
        y++;
    }
});
```

Hey guys,

the code above doesn't work as it was expected when changing tabs in Google Chrome, although it prints "Hello" in the console, it doesn't reset the title of the document to "title".
In Firefox and IE it works.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable's name to something other than `focus` as it is likely to be causing a conflict.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I changed the variable's name, but no adjustment. :(

Comment: Yes, its odd. It worked for me once or twice, but not consistently. Maybe someone else has a suggestion.